# Journaltitle and journal alias in Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, jabref

I use Jabref for my `bib` files and even in Biblatex mode, the journal title is still saved under `journal`. Since updating Biblatex, it no longer supports this backwards compatibility so journal titles are not appearing in my bibliography.

I could find+replace `journal =` to `journaltitle =` in my `bib` file but then Jabref doesn't recognise the title and I can't manage the journal abbreviations using the built-in functions.

So I would like to make Biblatex recognise `journal` as an alias for `journaltitle`. I tried

```
\renewbibmacro*{journal}{%
  \iffieldundef{journal}
   {}
   {\printtext[journaltitle]{%
      \printfield[titlecase]{journal}%
      \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
      \printfield[titlecase]{journalsubtitle}}}}
```

in the `bbx` file but this didn't work. Does anybody have any ideas?

### Edit 1: MWE

Here is an example of what I mean. Change `journal` to `journaltitle` and the journal title appears in the references. Otherwise it doesn't.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{elvis,
    author = "Elvis Presley",
    title = "Turn Me One More Time",
    journal = "Jail House Books",
    year = 1963,
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Here is a citation by \textcite{elvis}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

### Edit 2

I have `biber 1.4` and `biblatex 2.3` rather than `2.4`... I've tried updating but the MikTex package manager says everything is up to date. Could this be the problem? Also during the build, a warning appears saying `Found biblatex control file version 2.1, expected version 2.2` Could this also be a problem?

Also, I'm using MikTex 2.9

From my last update log (which is when this problem arose), four packages were updated,

```
extracting files from glossaries.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-biber-bin.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-misc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-texinfo-base.tar.lzma...
```

So it seems something in `biber` was updated.

Comment: `journal` has always been an alias for `journaltitle`. You'll have to provide some details so that we can help troubleshoot.

Comment: Biblatex automatically maps `journal` to `journaltitle` when creating `bbl` files from `bib` databases.  So using `\iffieldundef{journaltitle}` and `\printfield[titlecase]{journaltitle}` instead of `\iffieldundef{journal}` and `\printfield[titlecase]{journal}` should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks very much for looking at this. Unfortunately it still doesn't work. I've added an MWE that reproduces the problem for me. Fyi, all my packages are up to date.

Comment: @J-P We'll need more than an MWE, unfortunately. Your example shows no issues on my end. I tested with biblatex 2.4 and biber 1.4.

Comment: That is interesting. I've included info about my package versions in the question as well as update log info in case that provides any clues.

Comment: @J-P biblatex 2.3 won't work properly with biber 1.4. The biblatex manual gives a list of compatible versions. The [MiKTeX site](http://miktex.org/packages/biblatex) indicates that the latest package repo should have biblatex 2.4.

Comment: Sigh, another package version conflict... As it happens, I was updating using _Update (Admin)_ which was updating my main texmf tree but other packages were stored in a _Roaming_ profile. Updating using _Update_ fixed everything. Thanks very much for your help.